# Python merging two lists with variable size

Tags: python

Two lists A and B and both are in ascending order. Create a new list which has all elements of A & B and are in sorted.

```
Example 
2 1
3
6
1
```

Comment: What is the question here? What code did you try?

Comment: Usually input values are variable.

Comment: Use the [Merge Algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm).

Comment: Does any of the answer helps? If not please tell what do you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a potential solution to the question. Alas, you should also post your own code attempts.

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())

l1 = [int(input()) for i in range(n1)]
l2 = [int(input()) for i in range(n2)]

print(sorted(l1+l2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `heapq`:

```
n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())

list1 = [int(input()) for _ in range(n1)]
list2 = [int(input()) for _ in range(n2)]
```

---

```
from heapq import merge
res = list(merge(list1, list2))
```

OR

```
list1.extend(list2)
sorted(list1)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It helped. I accepted PApostol's answer as it was the first provided solution.. thanks to both :)

Answer (score 0):

To merge two lists you need this code:

```
list = list2 + list3
print(list)
```

To sort use this:

```
list.sort() # replace 'list' with your list name
```

To sort in descending order:

```
list.sort(reverse=True) # replace 'list' with your list name
```